# ifelse conditional formatting in r

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm relatively new to R.  I have a data frame, in which I would like to create a variable that does conditional formatting.  Below is a sample of the data that I am working with.

```
cycle <- c("M", "O", "O", "O", "O", "M", "O")
irm <- c("200901", "200902", "200903", "200904", "200905", "200906", "200907")
itemcode <- c("611420B004A01", "611420B004A01", "611420B004A01", "611420B004A01", "611420B004A01", "611420B004A01", "611420B004A01")
price <- c(19.00, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
dlq <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(itemcode, irm, price, cycle, dlq)
```

The dlq variable is conditional on the value of the cycle variable.  I would like to define it such that, for every unique value of itemcode (I have 75,000 of them)

> a.  dlq = 1 if price = NA during a month where cycle is equal to M or
>
> b.  dlq = 1 if cycle is equal to O & price = NA and the most recent month where cycle = M price = NA.
>
> c.  dlq = 0 otherwise.

For example, dlq = 1 where irm = 200907 because cycle = M in 200906 and price was equal to NA and it's also empty where irm = 200907.  I've tried using lead and lag variables, but the number of months between an M and an O is not constant.  So, I want dlq = 1 if and only if cycle = "O" and price = NA in the last month where cycle = M.  Is there a way to do this with ifelse or some other conditions?  Any advice/help would be much appreciated.  Thanks so much.

Comment: your price variable should be numeric, yes?

Comment: Yes @rawr it should be numeric, NA values notwithstanding

Comment: @rawr I just edited the question, sorry for the confusion. there was an additional condition I missed.

Comment: `irm` is currently a factor variable. if you wish to use it as a date, you need to do some data munging. After that, it's a relatively easy case of split-apply-combine, for which I suggest `library(data.table)` or `library(dplyr)`. IE- write a function that works for a single `itemcode` then `DT[, func(.SD), by= itemcode]`

Comment: @Alex i'm not sure I understand what you mean by "data munging".  Do you mean process irm as.date?

Comment: munging / wrangling / recoding / manipulation... they all mean the same thing. I prefer the term [munging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_wrangling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> df$dlq[ is.na(df$price)&df$cycle=="M" ] <- 1
> df$dlq[ is.na(df$price) & df$cycle=="O" & 
          is.na( c(NA, head(df$price,-1))) & # The last two conditions use shifted values
          c(FALSE, head(df$cycle,-1)=="M")  ] <- 1
> df
  cycle    irm      itemcode price dlq
1     M 200901 611420B004A01    19   0
2     O 200902 611420B004A01    NA   0
3     O 200903 611420B004A01    NA   0
4     O 200904 611420B004A01    NA   0
5     O 200905 611420B004A01    NA   0
6     M 200906 611420B004A01    NA   1
7     O 200907 611420B004A01    NA   1
```

Comment: this is quite good, but it doesn't seem to work for condition b.  I'm not quite sure why it works in this example and not my full dataframe.  Perhaps because it doesn't use irm as a date?

Comment: Well `irm` is not a date or anything like a date. It's a character vector.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's meant to be a date.  Do you think that would help?

Comment: I have no idea. Since the initial version of the question had it as a character and it appeared to rely on a simple sequence of rows, there was no checking for date-related issues. If there are gaps in your records, then it will be more complex and you need to define all the issues that will arise.

Answer (score 1):

```
> library('plyr');library('dplyr')
> df %>% tbl_df %>% mutate(dlq=ifelse((cycle=='M' & is.na(price))|((cycle=='O' & is.na(price)) & (cycle[nrow(.)]=='M' & is.na(price[nrow(.)]))),1,0))
Source: local data frame [7 x 5]

       itemcode    irm price  cycle   dlq
         (fctr) (fctr) (dbl) (fctr) (dbl)
1 611420B004A01 200901    19      M     0
2 611420B004A01 200902    NA      O     0
3 611420B004A01 200903    NA      O     0
4 611420B004A01 200904    NA      O     0
5 611420B004A01 200905    NA      O     0
6 611420B004A01 200906    NA      M     1
7 611420B004A01 200907    NA      O     0
```

Wonder if I misunderstand?

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work.  the dlq should be 1 for irm = 200907.  It may be because irm isn't used as a date, but I'm not sure yet.